# Is there a way to transform a picture to B&W in imagekit

Tags: imagekit

Is there a way to transform an image a have on imagekit to black and white via the API?

Something like this https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/tr:oi-logo-white_SJwqB4Nfe.png/medium_cafe_B1iTdD0C.jpg but for black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `e-grayscale` transformation on your image like this - https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/tr:oi-logo-white_SJwqB4Nfe.png,e-grayscale/medium_cafe_B1iTdD0C.jpg